# What is a 'satellite' in solid state physics?

Tags: solid-state-physics, terminology, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, satellites

During a course, my professor talked about *satellites*. He defined them as an excitation which results in an electron-hole pair, in a system of interacting electrons. So that the energy of the excitation is not simply the energy of the single electron which was excited but there is another contribution. Therefore it is not simply a “standard” electron-hole pair. Than he said that in the case of these excitations it appears also a boson (in the same level of the hole).
How can this be explained? Which kind of boson are we talking about?
Is there something more about satellites? I didn’t find a lot on the internet.

Comment: I've never heard of the term "satellite" in this context, but it sounds to me like an *exciton*, which you'll find plenty of information on if you search for it